# Accessing state values in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm somewhat new to reactjs. In **React.createclass** element you can access an input value or any state value such as this

```
  change: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },
```

However in **React.component** this is not possible, so how can I achieve the similar task in **React.component**

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as `React.component` as far as I can tell from the docs. Do you mean `React.Component` as in `class extends React.Component`? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass methods to event handlers like this `onChange={ this.change }` and use `ES2015` classes, you have to set `this` for these methods by yourself, for example

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { author: '' };
    this.change = this.change.bind(this); // set this for change method
  }

  change(e) {
    this.setState({ author: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return <input onChange={ this.change } value={ this.state.author } /> 
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42651/)